# sympy derivative with boolean

Tags: boolean, sympy, derivative

I am trying to take the derivative of a function including a boolean variable with sympy.

***My expected result:***

Two different derivatives, depending on the boolean being either True or False (i.e. 1 or 0).

***Example:***

```
import sympy as sy
c, x = sy.symbols("c x", positive=True, real=True)
bo = sy.Function("bo")
fct1 = sy.Function("fct1")
fct2 = sy.Function("fct2")
FOC2 = sy.Function("FOC2")
y = 5
a = 2
b = 4


def fct1(x):
    return -0.004*x**2 + 0.25*x + 4
# the following gives the smaller positive intercept with the x-axis)
# this intercept is the threshold value for the boolean function, bo
min(sy.solve(fct1(x)-y, x))


def bo(x):
    if fct1(x) <= y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def fct2(c, x):
    return a + b*c + bo(x)*c


def FOC2(c, x):
    return sy.diff(fct2(c, x), c)
print(FOC2(c, x))
```

The min-function after the comments shows me the threshold of x for bo being True or False would be 4.29..., thus positive and real.

***Output:***

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relation
```

I understand that the truth value depends on x, which is a symbol. Thus, without knowing x one cannot determine bo.

But how would I get my expected result, where bo is symbolic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would advise you to carefully consider what is going on in your code the way it is pasted above. You first define a few sympy functions, e.g.

```
fct1 = sy.Function("fct1")
```

So after this, `fct1` is an undefined `sympy.Function` - undefined in the sense that it is neither specified what its arguments are, nor what the function looks like.

However, then you define same-named functions explicitly, as in

```
def fct1(x):
    return -0.004*x**2 + 0.25*x + 4
```

Note however, that at this point, `fct1` ceases to be a `sympy.Function`, or any sympy object for that matter: you overwrite the old definition, and it is now just a regular python function!

This is also the reason that you get the error: when you call `bo(x)`, python tries to evaluate

```
-0.004*x**2 + 0.25*x + 4 <= 5
```

and return a value according to your definition of `bo()`. But python does not know whether the above is true (or how to make that comparison), so it complains.

I would suggest 2 changes:

1. Instead of python functions, as in the code, you could simply use sympy expressions, e.g.

   `fct1 = -0.004*x**2 + 0.25*x + 4`
2. To get the truth value of your condition, I would suggest to use the [Heaviside function (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), which evaluates to 0 for a negative argument, and to 1 for positive. Its implementation in sympy is [`sympy.Heaviside`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#heaviside).
   Your code could then look as follows:

```
import sympy as sy
c, x = sy.symbols("c x", positive=True, real=True)
y = 5
a = 2
b = 4


fct1 = -0.004*x**2 + 0.25*x + 4
bo = sy.Heaviside(y - fct1)
fct2 = a + b*c + bo * c

FOC2 = sy.diff(fct2, c)

print(FOC2)
```

Two comments on the line

```
bo = sy.Heaviside(y - fct1)
```

(1) The current implementation does not evaluate `sympy.Heaviside(0)`by default; this is beacause there's differing definitions around (some define it to be 1, others 1/2). You'd want it to be 1, to be in accordance with the (weak) inequality in the OP. In sympy 1.1, this can be achieved by passing an additional argument to `Heaviside`, namely whatever you want `Heaviside(0)` to evaluate to:

```
bo = sy.Heaviside(y - fct1, 1)
```

This is not supported in older versions of sympy.

(2) You will get your FOC2, again involving a `Heaviside` term. What I like about this, is that you could keep working with this expression, say if you wanted to take a second derivative and so on. If, for the sake of readability, you would prefer a piecewise expression - no problem. Just replace the according line with

```
bo = sy.Heaviside(y - fct1)._eval_rewrite_as_Piecewise(y-fct1)
```

Which will translate to a piecewise function automatically. (note that under older versions, this automatically implicitly uses Heaviside(0) = 0.5 - best to use (1) and (2) together:

```
bo = sy.Heaviside(y - fct1, 1)._eval_rewrite_as_Piecewise(y-fct1)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a working sympy 1.1 at my hands right now and can only test the old code.

One more noteconcerning sympy's piecewise functions: they are much more readable if using sympy's latex printing, by inserting

```
sy.init_printing()
```

early in the code.

(Disclaimer: I am by no means an expert in sympy, and there might be other, preferable solutions out there. Just trying to make a suggestion!)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and the comment on my code. Your idea works well for the question I posed. After taking the FOCs wrt. some symbolic variables, I am trying to solve the system of FOCs for these symbolic variables. It looks like I cannot do that with Heaviside? Using sy.solve_triangulated gives me an PolynomialError, stating that the Heaviside expression contains an element of the generators set. Any thoughts?